# Rich text editor - React Draft Wysiwyg - delete images from server

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, rich-text-editor, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am developing a React app. I'm storing my data and files in firebase realtime db / firebase storage.
I'm trying to implement React Draft Wysiwyg in my app but face some problems with deleting removed images from the database.
I'm using the uploadCallback parameter to upload the images to firebase, but I didn't find any parameter or event being fired in the docs after deleting an image, resulting in unused images in my firebase app and wasted storage.

Is there something I'm missing or a more complicated solution / using a different package is required?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to delete the images